# DataView and a custom template that will wrap all items

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a container with DataView type:

```
Ext.define('CustomView', {
    extend: 'Ext.DataView'
});
```

Also, I have a remote store that contains: `[{id: 1, name: 'abc'}, {id: 2, name: 'test'}]`.

I want to display those items in dataview in this way in html:

```
<ul>
     <li>abc</li>
     <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

In Sencha Touch 1 we can achieve that by setting tpl config and `<tpl for=".">` xtemplate tag. In Sencha Tocuh 2 it doesn't work anymore because setTpl works only when 'data' is present and I use a store. setItemTpl sets a template for each item so it doesn't work either. I could render manually the template and use setHtml but the 'tap' event wouldn't work on items.

How can I set my template to make it render the needed html in SC2 keeping the tap event?

Comment: Any reason you can't use a `listview`? I didn't understand why `setItemTpl` doesn't work. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Jayraj because listview is the same as dataview but provides additional list features that I don't need. `setItemTpl` sets tpl for each item, so i will get two ul-s: `<ul><li>abc</li></ul><ul><li>test</li></ul>`.

Comment: Is this `[{id: 1, name: 'abc'}, {id: 2, name: 'test'}]` supposed to be one row in your view or two rows?

Comment: @Jayraj it's supposed to render the html I posted in my question for 2 items.

Comment: Yes I understand that. but why not specify `itemTpl: "<li>{name}<li>"` and use the `getData` method on your store to get the data? That way you can use a regular `listview` and have the `tap` event. Unless you specifically want ONLY `<ul><li>etc<li><li>etc</li></ul>` and absolutely no other markup.

Comment: I want exactly `<ul><li>etc<li><li>etc</li></ul>`. Because i want to have it my own layout that differs from sencha touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataview` is used for custom renders of stores ([Sencha Docs Dataview](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView)).

"Use DataView whenever you want to show sets of the same component many times"

Unfortunately, it too has the same restriction as `listview` in that you can only specify an `itemTpl` (or `dataitem`) and can't control the markup generated for the entire component.

I think your best option is to create a custom view using a `panel` and writing the `store` reading logic yourself.

Comment: How would I change the markup for the entire panel? I think I only have layout to arrange my items and tpl config that works only with data... the same problem. It's weird that sencha team changed the behavior, you could do many useful things with tpl and itemSelector in version 1. ;(

Comment: `panel` s support XTemplate in Sencha Touch 2. The `tpl` config property can be used to specify whatever XTemplate you want to write. And the `data` config can be used to specify the data you want to apply to `tpl`.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, dataview has `tpl` and `data` too. But I can't use `data` because I use `store` with ajax to retrieve data.

Comment: So you can use the store's `getData` method to get its data right? And use that value in the panel's config?

Comment: Then I'd need to get data before the panel is rendered and repaint it for pull-to-update and paging... Looks complicated, but I think it's the only way. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to get the data before the panel is rendered, necessarily; it would be pulled when the panel instance is created. It would be something like `Ext.define("MyPanel", { extends: "Ext.Panel", config: { ... , data: myStore.getData(),  ..}});` . It's true that the view wouldn't update automatically though; you'd have to refresh it every time you perform a `store` `load`

Comment: It's a store with ajax, it will get data only after ajax request is completed.